# Highest sampling rate with SoX recording

Tags: sox

What would be the highest sampling rate I can specify for recording in SoX?  I have a microphone device incorporating a high speed sampling card.  I would like to record signals at 16 bit and either 384 kHz or ideally 500 kHz sampling rate.  My reading did not find any mention that SoX was limited. The application ARECORD only allows up to 192 kHz.